# H2O MOJO thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, h2o, mojo

I am using Mojo model for scoring my queries. I am using this statement to use mojo model

```
EasyPredictModelWrapper model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(MojoModel.load("gbm.zip"));
```

The question is can i use this model object from different threads? Is it thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the GBM MOJO with the Easy Wrapper (i.e. what is shown in the question) is thread-safe.

Here is an example showing a GBM MOJO model being initialized in a static block as part of a java servlet deployment:

- https://github.com/h2oai/app-mojo-servlet/blob/master/src/main/java/ai/h2o/PredictServlet.java