# Is H2O MOJO threadsafe? - xgboost

Tags: java, machine-learning, thread-safety, h2o, xgboost

This is very similar to [H2O MOJO thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235467/h2o-mojo-thread-safe) but for [xgboost](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html).

h2o document [Productionizing H2O](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html) does not seem to mention anything about it.
Is it thread safe to do this in a thread without a lock?

```
BinomialModelPrediction p = model.predictBinomial(row);
```

Or a more general question, [How to view a MOJO model](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/overview-summary.html#viewing-a-mojo) this document give me the impression the mojos of all these different types of models are essentially (if-else) decision tree and difference is about just how they are trained. is it true?

**UPDATE 4**:

[Productionizing H2O FAQ](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html#faq)

> Are MOJOs thread safe?
>
> Yes, all of H2O-3 MOJOs are thread safe.

**UPDATE 3**:

It's like h2o has its own java prediction implementation and likely threadsafe looking at the numbers [xgboost-predictor](https://github.com/h2oai/xgboost-predictor#benchmark).

**UPDATE 2**:

This [thread](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3371) cast some shadow, that xgboost may not be threadsafe for prediction. [XGBoostJavaMojoModel](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel-extensions/xgboost/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/algos/xgboost/XGBoostJavaMojoModel.java)

**UPDATE 1**:

> Transform ML models into a native code (Java, C, Python, Go, JavaScript) with zero dependencies

[m2cgen](https://github.com/BayesWitnesses/m2cgen) make me think the answer to the generalized question is likely true.

Comment: XGBoost prediction is not thread-safe, but in the Java implementation it uses `synchronized` on `predict`: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/ee4f51a631e12523f7a6771d6446c99231c88b19/jvm-packages/xgboost4j/src/main/java/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/java/Booster.java#L288.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, XGBoost MOJO and XGBoost Java predictor are both thread-safe.

Comment: thanks for the answer and i assume you work for h2o and is the credible source. if you can add some reference it would be even great.